# create javascript object

Tags: javascript, object

I have this function

```
// add history paths and save data
function AddPath( strTag, strUserName, arrayLatLngPoints, pathColour) {

  for (var i = 0; i < arrayLatLngPoints.length; i++)
    {
    var point = arrayLatLngPoints[i];
    var date = new Date( parseInt( point.timestamp));
    addMarkers(point.timestamp, point.lat, point.lng, point.timestamp, strUserName, pathColour, date.toString());
    date = null; 
    }
}
```

as well as adding the markers with addMarkers() i want to store the lat, long and timestamp in an object.

I was thinking the best way to store would be like this

```
{ strUserName : { timestamp : point.timestamp , LatLng : point.LatLng }, strUserName : { timestamp : point.timestamp , LatLng : point.LatLng } }
```

or

```
{ strUserName : { timestamp : point.timestamp , LatLng : { lat : point.lat, lng : point.lng } }, ..
```

How can i create this object?

**UPDATE:**

Thanks for the replies.
I have tried the following..

```
// add history paths and save data
function AddPath( strTag, strUserName, arrayLatLngPoints, pathColour) {

  for (var i = 0; i < arrayLatLngPoints.length; i++)
    {
    var point = arrayLatLngPoints[i];
    var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(point.lat, point.lng);

    var history = {
        strUserName : {
            timestamp : point.timestamp ,
            LatLng : pos
        }
    };

    var date = new Date( parseInt( point.timestamp));
    addMarkers(point.timestamp, point.lat, point.lng, point.timestamp, strUserName, pathColour, date.toString());
    date = null; 
    }
console.log(history);
}
```

see screenshot of console
[image: screenshot]

the username has not worked and im not getting an item for each timestamp, its just overwriting the one entry?

Comment: And what's the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can i create this object?

Pretty much exactly like you did:

```
var obj = { strUserName : { timestamp : point.timestamp , LatLng : point.LatLng }, strUserName : { timestamp : point.timestamp , LatLng : point.LatLng } };
```

Or more readably:

```
var obj = {
    strUserName : {
        timestamp : point.timestamp ,
        LatLng : point.LatLng
    },
    strUserName : {
        timestamp : point.timestamp ,
        LatLng : point.LatLng
    }
};
```

That's an [object initializer](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.1.5). It creates a new object with the given properties (actually, three new objects) and returns a reference to the outermost of them.

Taking some simpler examples:

```
// Create a blank object (an object with no properties of its own):
var a = {};

// Create an object with a `name` property with the value "Fred"
var b = {name: "Fred"};

// Create an object with a `foo` property, which is *another* freshly-created
// object with a `name` property with the value "Barney"
var c = {
    foo: {
        name: "Barney"
    }
};
```

---

Re your updated question:

> the username has not worked and im not getting an item for each timestamp, its just overwriting the one entry?

Of course it is, you're overwriting `history` on each loop, without storing the earlier copy anywhere. For instance, you can store them in an array:

```
// add history paths and save data
function AddPath( strTag, strUserName, arrayLatLngPoints, pathColour) {

  var historyArray = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arrayLatLngPoints.length; i++)
    {
    var point = arrayLatLngPoints[i];
    var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(point.lat, point.lng);

    historyArray[i] = {
        strUserName : {
            timestamp : point.timestamp ,
            LatLng : pos
        }
    };

    var date = new Date( parseInt( point.timestamp));
    addMarkers(point.timestamp, point.lat, point.lng, point.timestamp, strUserName, pathColour, date.toString());
    date = null; 
    }
console.log(historyArray);
}
```

Comment: @VinceLowe: *"the username has not worked and im not getting an item for each timestamp, its just overwriting the one entry?"* Of course it is, you're overwriting `history` on each loop, without storing the earlier copy anywhere. I've updated the answer to show *one* possible way you might store them (in an array).

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj = {strUserName: {timestamp: point.timestamp, lat: point.lat, long: point.long}}
```