# How Would I Create An Object In JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

To be more specific, I need to essentially create an object where I can store and read values.

I'm a bit of a noob in JS, so I'm sorry if my understanding is limited. I'll give an example.

```
var usrobj = mainobj.id(userIDHere);
var usrplays = usrobj.plays;
```

Stuff like that.

But, I also would need to write to the plays value. Any ideas?? (I don't know a crap ton about JavaScript, compared to most of you)

Comment: Come to the JavaScript room, we'll make you a pro in no time! (You just need 20 rep)

Comment: [MDN's Working With Objects article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects). Or _any_ half-decent JS tutorial.

Comment: reason for down vote: this question's answer is obviously somewhere that google can find on the internet.

Comment: `var someObject = {}; // hey, it's an object!`

Comment: Reason for upvote: We are here to create the google search results.

Comment: @adrichman this question has never been questioned on SO, and the purpose of SO is to answer all of the programming questions immaginable, and SO wants to be at the top list of google searches, but how can it if it has no object declaration question? So I'd consider upvoting so he can enter the js room and we can help him out with all of the basic needs of a `new Javascripter()`

Comment: I searched SO for "create javascript object" and got many responses, such as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11308981/create-javascript-object . I understand all of the points being made here, but there is also a guideline for not supporting questions that were asked without sufficient research. Luckily though, we all get a say :)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because a basic understanding of the topic must be present

Comment: @t1wc - SO's purpose can't be to answer _all_ programming questions imaginable, because some of the available question close reasons directly exclude many imaginable questions. (I'll try to resist commenting on how silly and counterproductive I think that number one Google goal is for questions that are already answered clearly in library API documentation - why would SO want to beat out, say, api.jquery.com for Google searches about basic use of jQuery methods?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objects are really awesome in js because they are so simple. You can create an object as simply as:

```
var usrobj = {};
```

That is all you need. You can then add keys to it as easily as:

```
userobj.plays = somevalue;
```

And then read from it as easily as:

```
console.log(userobj.plays);
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yknow what. I feel like an idiot right now. xD

Thank you. <3

Comment: @WesleyBellah come in the js chat anyway, we can teach you much more than this.
[remember this thing and click it when you have at least 20 reputation](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript)